# Creating a new column in pandas based on length of unique values from other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as below:

```
df

    id   val
0    1   21
1    2   35
2    2   45
3    3   55
4    1   10
5    4   90
6    3   45
7    2   78
8    3   23
```

I want to create a new column `cat` based on length of each value in `id`.

if len(id) <= 1 value in `cat` should be 'A'

if len(id) < 3 value should be 'B'

if len(id) >= 3 value should be 'C'

Expected Output:

```
    id   val   cat
0    1   21     B
1    2   35     C
2    2   45     C
3    3   55     C
4    1   10     B
5    4   90     A
6    3   45     C
7    2   78     C
8    3   23     C
```

what I tried:

```
def test(series):
    if len(series) <= 1:
        return 'A'
    elif len(series) < 3:
        return 'B'
    else:
        return 'C'


df.groupby('id').apply(test)
```

Error for above code:

> TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Comment: As shown below, I [cannot reproduce your error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49497852/567620) and the code you posted in the original question works as expected. The "hash" error message suggests your error was actually related to trying to merge the result of the `groupby` operation back into the original DataFrame,  so it would be helpful if you posted that part of the code too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `map`, `value_counts` and `pd.cut`:

```
 df['cat'] = df.id.map(pd.cut(df.id.value_counts(),
                              bins=[0,1,2,np.inf],
                              labels=['A','B','C']))
```

Output:

```
   id  val cat
0   1   21   B
1   2   35   C
2   2   45   C
3   3   55   C
4   1   10   B
5   4   90   A
6   3   45   C
7   2   78   C
8   3   23   C
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a more straightforward way using `pd.Series.value_counts` and `np.where`.

Where possible, avoid using `pd.Series.apply` as this is just a thinly veiled loop. The power of pandas is generally only apparent when you can *vectorise* calculations.

```
df['count'] = df['id'].map(df['id'].value_counts())

df['cat'] = np.where(df['count'] <= 1, 'A',
                     np.where(df['count'] < 3, 'B', 'C'))

#    id  val  count cat
# 0   1   21      2   B
# 1   2   35      3   C
# 2   2   45      3   C
# 3   3   55      3   C
# 4   1   10      2   B
# 5   4   90      1   A
# 6   3   45      3   C
# 7   2   78      3   C
# 8   3   23      3   C
```

Comment: @jezrael, yeh - you can edit the question, remove `print` and retag. Up to you :)

Comment: Same as everyone.. 1000 for gold.. so I'm making it practice now, if code only works in python 3.x, then mark as python 3.x. Don't see the harm, or how it's misleading. Someone can roll back or edit if they really care. Same for 2.x

Comment: Around half way :).

Comment: SO isn't my job :). Also, I see *so many* 3.x questions that are clear duplicates and it's sad to see them poorly answered.

Comment: @jezrael, sorry not implying it was. Just I have other things to do. In short, I save time if I get the tag sooner. Tagging is easy, writing up a wiki-solution to a clear dup to push away rep-seekers on dup is hard work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a value counts of the id columns as

```
x=df['id'].value_counts()
x=pd.DataFrame(x)
x.columns=['id','cat']
```

convert it into a pandas DataFrame and perform a left join

```
pd.merge(df,x,on='id',how='left')
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your error when using Python 3.6.2 and Pandas 0.21.0. Your original code works as expected, and can be used with `pandas.merge` to get the output you desired:

```
In [2]: pandas.__version__
Out[2]: '0.21.0'

In [3]: df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 3], 
    'val': [21, 35, 45, 55, 10, 90, 45, 78, 23]
})

In [4]: def test(series):
   ...:     if len(series) <= 1:
   ...:         return 'A'
   ...:     elif len(series) < 3:
   ...:         return 'B'
   ...:     else:
   ...:         return 'C'
   ...:         

In [5]: pandas.merge(
    df, 
    pandas.DataFrame({'cat': df.groupby('id').apply(test)}),
    left_on='id', 
    right_index=True, 
    how='right'
)
Out[5]: 
   id  val cat
0   1   21   B
4   1   10   B
1   2   35   C
2   2   45   C
7   2   78   C
3   3   55   C
6   3   45   C
8   3   23   C
5   4   90   A

In [6]: df.groupby('id').apply(test)
Out[6]: 
id
1    B
2    C
3    C
4    A
dtype: object
```